# How to fix 'ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function'?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I am creating a new application and I want to parse an array into a "json" file in ionic 3 but it says `ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function;` What can I do to solve this problem?

```
if(this.file) {
  console.log(this.userJsonUrl);
  this.file.writeFile(this.file.dataDirectory, "users.json", "Hello world",
    { replace: true }).then(done => alert('ok')).catch(err => alert('ok'))
  console.log('File created')
}
```

and this is the full error

> ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
>   at File.get [as dataDirectory] (index.js:649)
>   at RegisterPage.webpackJsonp.204.RegisterPage.register (register.ts:62)
>   at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (RegisterPage.ngfactory.js:116)
>   at Object.handleEvent (core.es5.js:12023)
>   at Object.handleEvent (core.es5.js:12756)
>   at dispatchEvent (core.es5.js:8615)
>   at core.es5.js:9226
>   at HTMLButtonElement. (platform-browser.es5.js:2651)
>   at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
>   at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)

Comment: can you provide the code?

Comment: show your code. How we can help you without it?

Comment: i'm sorry its my first post ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is related to **[`@ionic-native/file`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/file/)**.

If you install `@ionic-native/file` using `npm install --save @ionic-native/file` uninstall it using `npm uninstall --save @ionic-native/file`.

As your app is using Ionic 3, you should install `@ionic-native/file` with **`@4`.**

**`npm install --save @ionic-native/file@4`**